# Get the date and time for specified timezone

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, utc

I have a server in the UK (GMT+1), and I need to store a date for Canada (GMT-5). This is relatively simple.

```
//gmt_operator, gmt_hr, gmt_min are all grabbed from a database
//These are the data extracted from GTM+5:00 for example.

//Get UTC+00:00 in seconds
time_t ltime;
time(&ltime);
//Add GMT offset
if (gmt_operator == '+')
    ltime = ltime + (gmt_hr*60*60) + (gmt_min*60);
else if (gmt_operator  == '-')
    ltime = ltime - (gmt_hr*60*60) - (gmt_min*60);
else
    return NULL;
char buff[9];
struct tm * mydate= gmtime(&ltime);
strftime(buff, sizeof(buff), "%Y%m%d", today);
return buff;
```

> I cant use a tm struct before adding the offset, since if i convert ltime to a tm struct than add the hours and minutes, I might get an overflow of hours and minutes. This can be fixed with mktime(), but mktime will also convert to localtime, which i do not want.

There is a small problem with this solution. The time is still 1 hour off. This is because of the current daylight savings time that is in affect. The functions localtime() and mktime() grabs this somehow, but these functions only grab it for the servers local time, but i need it for a specified one, like GMT-5:00 or GMT+2:00.

This is brand new territory for me, and I would appreciate some incite into a possible solution. I hope this isn't a duplicate, but i have not found a similar question to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct so far. The meaning of "GMT-5:00" and "GMT+2:00" is always the same, and has nothing do with DST (daylight saving time aka summer time).

In other words, the DST already needs to be included in those specs.

For example, in center europe you can't just say "GMT+01". You have CET and CEST, which means "GMT+01" or "GMT+02".

Comment: So my data source should be correcting these things? It should say GTM-4:00 during the summer?

Comment: If you mean GMT-4:00 (not GTM-4:00), then yes. It is as simple as that. The reason is simply that a spec like "GMT-5:00" doesn't say which country you mean. In that region, there may be some countries that have DST and other that have no DST, and yet another one that has DST for slightly different days per year. And that's just the surface of that topic. For that reason, the approach itself is flawed. Moreover, on every Unix/Linux system there is some `tz_data` package and functions that should take this work away from you.